# C# - HttpWebRequest / GetResponse performance

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, httpwebrequest, webresponse, servicepointmanager

I have a HTTPS based API which I need to call a lot of times. Using HttpWebRequest.Create(uri).GetResponse() takes from 50ms up to 500ms or more to execute. In order to check the response time I implemented it like this:

```
private void Action()
{
    WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://.....");
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) { }
}
```

and then calling it:

```
private long getTime()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    Action();
    return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

Output for several calls:

```
Time: 746 ms
Time: 51 ms
Time: 50 ms
Time: 50 ms
Time: 51 ms
Time: 49 ms
Time: 2417 ms ???
Time: 52 ms
Time: 52 ms
Time: 51 ms
Time: 50 ms
Time: 201 ms
Time: 234 ms
Time: 204 ms
Time: 51 ms
Time: 50 ms
Time: 50 ms
Time: 52 ms
Time: 280 ms
Time: 264 ms
```

**First QUESTION: I was wondering if there was any way to speed up GetResponse in order for it to take as less time as possible?**

Now.. because I need to make A LOT of different requests with different URLs, in order to speed up the process I decided to use `TPL Dataflow Block` (instead of `Parallel.Foreach`), since `Parallel.Foreach` is mainly used for `CPU bound` work, and what I am doing is `I/O bound` (there's also processing of the response, so also a bit of CPU work). And when I use TPL Dataflow Block the processing of 250 URLs takes up to 7 seconds to execute, whereas Parallel Foreach takes 15 seconds or more, so I'm positive TPL Dataflow Block usage is the right way to go. How I implemented it:

```
//CALL:
var block = new ActionBlock<string>(uri => Action(uri), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 200 });
foreach (var URL in urlArray)
{
    block.Post(URL);
}
block.Complete();
await block.Completion;

//Action(uri):
private void Action(string uri)
{
    WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) { }
}
```

And since I am not happy with 7s execution I've tried tweaking `ServicePointManager`in order to speed it up, things I've tried so far and NONE of it worked:

```
ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive(false, 0, 0);
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;
```

**Second QUESTION: If it is not possible speeding up `GetResponse()` in order to achieve faster execution, is there any way to tweak `TPL Dataflow Block` into having better performance?**

EDIT: My goal is to execute all calls AS FAST AS possible.

Comment: Why not using [GetResponseAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I am genuinely amazed how I missed that. Truly one of the most embarrassing moments of my life.. I must have been really tired. Please post your reply as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could speedup your solution by using [GetResponseAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync(v=vs.110).aspx). See also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/walkthrough-accessing-the-web-by-using-async-and-await) Micorsoft walkthrough where both methods (synchronous and asynchronous) are explained in depth.